# .NET - ASP.NET Cache Vs Couchbase cache

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching, couchbase

I have a large data-driven application simple WCF services.
I want to store some of my frequently used data in cache.
I have two options

1. ASP.NET Cache
2. Couchbase Cache

I practical perspective which of the cache is efficient, reliable and easy to use with WCF Services and .NET platform?

Comment: You looking only to cache the SQL data ?

Comment: yes, like list of all user profiles their like and interests etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends by your architecture and where you are going to deploy your project.

if by instance you will deploy your project on a server farm Asp.net cache would not be my first choice as it does not support distributes caching (Multiple cache copies not synchronized,Cache lost when worker process recycles,etc) so in this case I would use Couchbase (behind the scene uses a database).

If you will deploy your project on a single web server you may use the Asp.net caching

Comment: We will be deploying it on amazon ec2

Comment: you should refer to their documentation is this case:
http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2011/08/amazon-elasticache-distributed-in-memory-caching.html